# Fourier transform integration in time

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

Let $f(t)$ be a generic integrable function (where $t$ is time).
Let $F(\omega)$ be its Fourier transform.

Suppose every continuity and integrability condition is met. It is legit to say $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(\omega) e^{2i\pi\omega t} dt d\omega$ ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, under suitable conditions:
$$
    F(0)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-2\pi iw0}dt \\
   F(0)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(w)e^{2\pi i w t}dw\right)e^{-i2\pi i t 0} dt
$$

Comment: @LoScrondo : You have to correct $x$ in $F(x)$ to $F(w)$. Otherwise the inner integral doesn't exist.

Comment: Another typing error. I really apologize! That's the correct formula: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(\omega) e^{2i\pi\omega t} d\omega dt$